# Can not create shards: sharding not enabled for db

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I am trying shard collection based on a sharding key:
Looking into help I see that I can do this with 
`sh.shardCollection("database.collection", myKey)`

But when I am doing this I receive the message

```
{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "sharding not enabled for db" }
```

I started `mongod --configsvr` and also `mongod --shardsvr` , so I thought that I already enabled sharding. Any idea what should I do?

Comment: you have to run `enableSharding()` for that db

Answer (score 2):

Actually everything is pretty simple. All you need to do is to enable sharding for your database (yep it is kind of written in the error msg).

And you can do this with `sh.enableSharding(database)`

To see commands for sharding, you can do `sh.help()` and this will output you are list of commands with their description. There you can find this enableSharding.

Also keep in mind that you need to have indeces on your myKey before you can do sharding (otherwise you will receive some error about indeces). So if you have not done this - create them before with `db.collection.ensureIndex(myKey)`

Answer (score 0):

for example this adds a hashed shard index and shard key to the generated _id field - don't recommend using this, it's just an example of how to get sharding enabled

```
sh.enableSharding("mydatabase")
use mydatabase
var shardKey = { "_id": "hashed" }
db.customers.createIndex(shardKey)
sh.shardCollection( "mydatabase.customers", shardKey)
```